# Why position is not quantized in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, discrete

Usually in all the standard examples in quantum mechanics textbooks the spectrum of the position operator is continuous.

Are there (nontrivial) examples where position is quantized? or position quantization is forbidden for some fundamental reason in quantum mechanics (what is that reason?)?

Update: By position quantization I mean, if position (of a particle say) is measured we get only a discrete spectrum (say 2.5 cm and 2.7 cm, but nothing in between, just in the same way that energy levels can be discrete). In that sense interference patter of photons on a photographic plate cannot be considered as position quantization because the probability density varies "continuously" from maximum to zero (or am I wrong?)

Comment: position quantization is equivalent to periodic momentum, and this happens in a crystal. Position is quantized in a crystal, on a grid.

Answer (score 15):

Position quantization in vacuum is forbidden by rotational, translational, and boost invariance. There is no rotationally invariant grid. On the other hand, if you have electrons in a periodic potential, the result in any one band is mathematically the theory of an electron on a discrete lattice. In this case, the position is quantized, so that the momentum is periodic with period p.

#### Fourier duality

The quasimomentum p in a crystal is defined as i times the log of the eigenvalue of the crystal translation operator acting eigenvector. Here I give the definition of crystal position operators and momentum operators, which are relevant in the tight-binding bands, and to describe the analog of the canonical commutation relations which these operators obey. These are the discrete space canonical commutation relations.

In 1d, consider a periodic potential of period 1, the translation by one unit on an energy eigenstate commutes with H, so it gives a phase, which you write as:

$$ e^{ip}$$

and for p in a Brillouin zone $-\pi<0<\pi$ this gives a unique phase. The p direction has become periodic with period $2\pi$. This means that any superposition of p waves is a periodic function in p-space.

The Fourier transform is a duality, and a periodic spatial coordinate leads to discrete p. In this case, the duality takes a periodic p to a discrete x. Define the dual position operator using eigenstates of position. The position
eigenstate is defined as follows on an infinite lattice:

$$ |x=0\rangle = \int_0^{2\pi} |p\rangle $$

Where the sum is over the Brillouin zone, and the sum is over *one band only*. This state comes with a whole family of others, which are translated by the lattice symmetry:

$$ |x=n\rangle = e^{iPn} |x=0\rangle = \int_0^{2\pi} e^{inp} |p\rangle $$

These are the only superpositions which are periodic on P space. This allows one to define the X operator as;

$$ X = \sum_n n |x=n\rangle\langle x=n| $$

The X operator has discrete eigenvalues, it tells you which atom you are bound to. It only takes you inside one band, it doesn't have matrix elements from band to band.

The commutation relations for the quasiposition X and quasimomentum P is derived from the fact that integer translation of X is accomplished by P:

$$ X+ n = e^{-inP} X e^{inP}$$

This is the lattice analog of the canonical commutation relation. It isn't infinitesimal. If you make the translation increment infinitesimal, the lattice goes away and it becomes Heisenberg's relation.

If you start with a free particle, any free $|p\rangle$ state is also a quasimomentum p state, but for any given quasimomentum p, all the states

$$ |p + 2\pi k\rangle $$

have the same quasimomentum for any integer k. If you add a small periodic potential and do perturbation theory, these different k-states at a fixed quasimomentum mix with each other to produce the bands, and the energy eigenstates $|p,n\rangle$ are labelled by the quasimomentum and the band number n:

you define the discrete position states as above for each band

$$ |x,n\rangle = \int_0^{2\pi} e^{inp} |p,n\rangle $$

These give you the discrete position operator and the discrete band number operator.

$$ N |x,n\rangle = n |x,n\rangle $$

if you further make the crystal of finite size, by imposing periodic boundaries in x, the discrete X become periodic and p becomes the Fourier dual lattice, so that the number of lattice points in x and in p are equal, but the increments are reciprocal.

This is what finite volume discrete space QM looks like, and it does not allow canonical commutators, since these only emerge at small lattice spacing.

Comment: Do you mean the "momentum" with period p or the position?

Comment: @annav: I mean the momentum periodic with period p which is the same as the position quantized is a lattice of size 2pi/p.

Comment: "Position quantization in vacuum is forbidden by rotational, translational, and boost invariance" Wow... This is an awesome insight that I never thought of. I always wondered myself if space was quantized, like at plank distance, for example. But if there was a "universal grid of spacetime" then you would loose translational and rotational symmetry of natural laws. And that would cost you conservation of linear and angular momentum respectively. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_(physics)#Conservation_laws_and_symmetry

Comment: Actually, if posistion in space was quantized, in order for translational and rotational symmetry to hold, and therefore, for the conservation laws to hold, wouldn't momentum need to be quantized? If mass, time, and energy were all quantized, wouldn't that be possible? Or no?

Comment: @John: I don't know if you're serious, but yes, you lose conservation laws. It's not completely trivial in field theory, because you can have emergent rotational invariance at long distances, like an atomic lattice can have rotationally invariant sound waves. This doesn't work because the corrections are going to be too big from natural lattice scale at the Planck scale. It also doesn't work in string theory, where the space is holographicaly reconstructed from the symmetries of the boundary, SUSY and spacetime, and you don't have a lattice, and the symmetry is the fundamental ingredient

Answer (score 8):

The answer is essentially what *Kostya* has pointed out:

Position is quantized but has a continuous spectrum of (generalized) eigenvalues because the [canonical commutation relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation) on position and momentum forbid that both of them be bounded operators (and act on finite-dimensional state spaces) [by Stone-von Neumann theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone-von_Neumann_theorem). This means that, given general constraints, at least one of them must be unbounded and thus must have a nonemtpy continuum spectrum, implying that the resolution of the identity must be in terms of an integral over non physical states. This is why in general a specific point-like position is not a physical observable eigenstate of a system, and must be spread over a dense interval (which is related to the instrumental resolution of the measurement): e.g. particles can have as much localized wave packets as our resolution allows, but they have no defined positions even in principle (at least in standard quantum mechanics). Thus the canonical commutation relations forbid you have discrete position if momentum is discrete by boundary conditions (e.g. [particle in a box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box)). This may seem trivial because position and momentum are the generators of translations of each other, but the point of the noncommutativity and the theorem is that one of them can indeed have discrete spectrum (usually boundary conditions discretize momentum, so position generalized eigenvalues are continuous).

Concering semantics of "quantized", some observable property is quantized if it is an operator in the quantum physical state of the system, regardless of the discreteness or continuity of its spectrum of eigenvalues because, even in the continuum case, it is subject to the formalism of quantum mechanics: noncommutativity, uncertainty, probabilistic expected values ... Quantum jumps in possible values of discrete spectra are just the most remarkable property of the quantum world, without analogue in the classical world, hence the name quantum mechanics, but that is not a necessary condition. Since there are purely quantum degrees of freedom (e.g. spin), quantization is not fundamental, but they are nevertheless quantum observables and not classical in both senses: spin observables belong to an operator algebra formalism, they are not a function on classical phase space, and have discrete spectrum, thus being quantized (or more properly, "quantum-mechanical") in any meaning of the word.

**UPDATE on crystal lattices:** what Ron is calling realization of discrete space might be very misleading. Any nonrelativistic space lattice model (i.e., in non quantum gravity theories) is an effective discrete model for constrained main expectation values of real position observables. The quasi-position/momentum of crystals, and thus crystal lattices of condensed matter, are an emergent property out of the symmetries of the approximate arrangement of equilibrium positions of many atoms. Any position measurement on any atom is however not point-like defined, but just highly localized around the lattice nodes. From a very rigorous point of view, one should distinguish the fundamental degrees of freedom of the system from effective quantities emergent from the system's symmetries. In the case of solid state matter, the system is composed of a huge collection of atoms which whose collective interactions constrain their localization around well-defined points of equilibrium. Therefore at the structural level we can talk about quasi-classical atoms at fixed positions (the maxima of their position probability distributions), thus creating an effective lattice of discrete quasi-position where the rest of the constraints and properties of the system (periodic potentials, momentum...) give an emergent model for quasi-particles which may seem like discretized space and momentum simultaneously. I defend that thinking of this as purely quantum mechanical position is misleading, because the lattice as a whole is classical, although discrete, as its structure is not subject to superpositions in a Hilbert space, to the noncommutativity and uncertainty principle, and its (constant) structure is not a static solution of a collective system's Schrödinger equation. The fundamental degrees of freedom are the quantum position and momentum operators of each atom, always subject to canonical commutation relations and thus continuum spectrum of one of the two, along with uncertainty in position-momentum. A quasi-position and quasi-momentum of a quasi-particle on a crystal lattice is NOT realized by the eigenstates of any actual quantum particle. In this sense, crystal lattices do not serve as example of "quantized position" (meaning discrete spectrum), as long as one retains the noun "position" to mean ordinary position. Real atoms in any crystal have nonzero bounded temperature, forbidding them to have definite constant positions: upon measuring position of any atoms in a crystal, the atom will appear localized with a distribution probability around the lattice node, but the real observable position of the atom need not be the node itself (in fact is always a region, since point-like positions are not eigenstates, only wave-packets).

The quantum model Ron talks about in his answer is useful and nice for the effective lattice I talked about above. I just do not call position to something which is not what we observe when measuring position on quantum particles, that is why I talk about quasi-position in that case. In absence of evidence for a discrete quantum spacetime, quantized phase space is what is traditionally called in theoretical physics as far as I know.
Therefore, any real quantum position and momentum, in the sense of the quantum operators whose expectation values "obey" (in the sense of [Ehrenfest Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem)) classical Hamilton equations, and whose Schrödinger evolution "obey" (in the sense of [eikonal approximations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation#Eikonal_approximation_and_relationship_to_the_Schr.C3.B6dinger_equation)) [classical Hamilton-Jacobi equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation), are not simultaneously discrete.

The only theories where quantum position gets discretized spectrum is in quantum gravity theories like l[oop quantum gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_quantum_gravity), where the fundamental degrees of freedom of space (and time) itself get quantized (do not confuse quantum position as before, which is newtonian position related to reference bodies, with position as understood in general relativity, where spacetime is the gravitational field). There you get a granular graph of nodes forming space itself, and our traditional continuum positions are just approximations (even at the atomic level) of the relational position given by a flat gravitational field.

Comment: I stated clearly what I meant by the word quantization in the question. I did not mean the quantization "procedure" by which one promote the classical momentum for example into an operator which equals $-i \hbar \nabla$. In that sense Spin is not quantized because it has no classical analog. Anyway, again, I was talking about the quantization of spectrum.

Comment: I have added more to my answer at the beginning, hoping to answer more concretely the discrete spectrum issue for position due to the canonical commutation relations.

Comment: -1: This answer is basically saying [x,p]=i means no quantized x. This is mathematically true, but both obvious and ridiculous--- the very idea of an infinitesimal generator of x translations means x is continuous from the beginning. The deduction is false for the example of a quasiparticles on a crystal lattice of finite volume where the quasiparticle momentum and position are both discrete. It's still QM, but canonical commutation fails, you get the discrete version with exponentials of P instead, and this is the right mathematical statement of discrete x. The rest is wordy and irrelevant.

Comment: Stone-von Neumann theorem is not obviously trivial and, along with the canonical commutation relations, they are not ridiculous because even if x and p are mutually infinitesimal generators of translations in each other's spectrum, one of them can indeed have discrete spectrum, but not both, and that is not obvious a priori. Quasi-position/momentum that do not obey the canonical commutator are not what I understand as position/momentum in the sense of quantized phase space of classical trayectories.

Comment: On the other hand, disqualifying other people's answer as wordy and irrelevant is subjective and unnecessary. Indeed it was a wordy answer (now trimmed to the obvious and ridiculous) but not irrelevant at all if the person who wants to know about quantization, spectra and position likes a deeper interrelation of ideas. For example a careful distinction between quantized observable and discrete spectrum and its relation to the different mathematical setting of classical and quantum mechanics. However, to satisfy users like Ron Maimon, some of us prefer to remain brief, obvious and ridiculous.

Comment: @JavierÁlvarez: I went overboard in criticism, probably because I was in a bad mood. The answer is not bad but intimidating because of the rigor, and it is just not true that you can't discretize x in QM. The actual proof of the Stone-Von-Neumann theorem proceeds by reformulating the canonical commutation condition using exponentiated unitary P's and X's that do translations on each other. If you replace P's by Brillouin zone P's and X's by lattice X's you get a fine alternate set of canonical commutators, just as good as the usual ones, except no rotational symmetry. These describe solids.

Comment: @RonMaimon: I am very interested, could you please provide a concrete bibliographic reference (or more if possible) dealing in detail with the so called alternate canonical commutators for those Brillouin zone P/X operators, and/or the deduction that quasiparticles have a discrete spectrum in both P and X? Thanks.

Comment: @JavierÁlvarez: No, I cannot give a reference, it is possible (although extremely unlikely) that nobody except me has said it this way. This is known as Fourier dual lattices in mathematics, it is well known, and the quantity pseudomomentum is dual to a crystal lattice position. The commutation is only on exponentiated P operators, as appear in Stone and Von-Neumann's paper, which _you_ cite.

Comment: @JavierÁlvarez: Ok, I read the extended answer--- I agree with the additions for the most part, but there is one point which I disagree very strongly--- even if you quantize the atomic lattice, so that you consider quanutm nuclei interacting with quantum electrons, you still get the discrete lattice emerging in a band. This holds even at finite temperature, up to the melting temperature, it's an example of spontaneous symmetry breaking of translation symmetry, and it doesn't depend on having an external potential. The only thing it requires is a very large system, so that you approximate SSB.

Comment: @RonMaimon: Ok. Our difference is more semantic than physical, I simply restrain myself from calling quantum position the observables that define your lattice, but that may be more a metaphysical and mathematical bias of mine. The lattice quasi-positions are new observables to model the system in those situations, but the traditional position-momentum observables of each particle are available then and in any other situation, and that is why I call them the real position-momentum, unless we know anything about quantum spacetime.

Comment: @JavierÁlvarez: You're right, we have no disagreement (but please fix the statement that this is wrecked by quantizing nuclear motions or by thermal jitter). But the point is that the effective theory of the lattice has a conserved quasimomentum that is dual to a discrete quasiposition, so it gives you information about what QM looks like in a discrete space. It isn't fundamental description at high energies, but it's a model that is available in nature, and it allows you to gain inisight about what discrete space theories do.

Comment: @RonMaimon: mmm... I do not find what you mean by "quantized nuclear motions", I did not talk about atoms inner structure at any point. Regarding thermal atomic vibrations, there is no clash or contradiction between that and the lattice model you talk about, I just mention it to point out that there is not such thing as observable atoms with definite point-like position even within a solid state structure. You are right those models are useful and insightful (maybe even for emergent gravity and discrete spacetimes), I am just very conservative regarding what to call space and spacetime.

Comment: @JavierÁlvarez: the whole discussion with "because the lattice itself is classical though discrete... real observable position ..." all that stuff is talking about quantizing nuclear translational motion (that's what "atomic position" means) and it is completely wrong. It doesn't matter if you have quantized or classical nuclei, you still have bands, and this persists at finite temperature until the crystal melts. It is also a wrong criticism of my answer, and your bringing up of Hamilton-Jacobi is a smoke screen. There is nothing wrong with discrete space quantum mechanics.

Comment: @RonMaimon: it seems you have difficulties with other people's attempts to justify their use of certain terminology if they don't agree with yours. Hamilton-Jacobi were brought up to help me clarify what I mean by position, i.e. any quantum observable whose coarse grained statistical behavior tends to the dynamics of a classical position observable. It does not matter how much you want bands and lattices to exemplify a discrete space quantum mechanics, no particle in any lattice or band has observable point-like eigenstates, thus no discrete spectrum, I don't mean any more than that.

Answer (score 7):

So, suppose you have an eigenstate of $\hat{x}$:
$$\hat{x}|\psi\rangle = x|\psi\rangle$$
Now let us act with $\hat{x}$ on $e^{i\hat{p}\delta}|\psi\rangle$, and [use this formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff_formula#The_Hadamard_lemma) (I have $\hbar=1$):
$$\hat{x}e^{i\hat{p}\delta}|\psi\rangle=e^{i\hat{p}\delta}\left(\hat{x}+i\delta[\hat{p},\hat{x}]+\frac{i\delta}{2!}[\hat{p},[\hat{p},\hat{x}]]+\frac{i\delta}{3!}[\hat{p},[\hat{p},[\hat{p},\hat{x}]]]+...\right)|\psi\rangle=$$
$$=e^{i\hat{p}\delta}(\hat{x}+\delta)|\psi\rangle=(x+\delta)e^{i\hat{p}\delta}|\psi\rangle$$
So you have another eigenstate, shifted at arbitrary distance $\delta$.

It seems that this result holds for any pair of observables with *constant* commutator.

Comment: From this derivation it seems it works for $[P,X]=f(X)$, where $f(X)$ might be more complicated than $1$. Then you don't get the $+\delta$, but a shift by a function of $\delta$ and the eigenvalue $x$. (I don't know about convergence and reality of the series though.)

Comment: This also assumes constant commutator. The commutation relation has to fail for discrete space time--- it fails for position and momentum operators for quasiparticles in the lattice, hence you get Brillouin zones. Reducing the dynamics of each band, you get the right lattice QM formulation. It's only physical problem is lack of symmetry, no rotations and no boosts.

Comment: @RonMaimon I'm really puzzled about this crystal thing everyone is talking about. As far as I remember the commutation relations for crystal modes are still $[x_k,q_l]=i\delta_{kl}$, aren't they?

Comment: @RonMaimon: I have the same problem as Kostya and have asked for references on details of the whole definition of the so called x/p operators in the case of crystals. I want to see please their deduction and interpretation. However discrete lattice anyone talks about, that cannot be fundamental, as atoms vibrate around equilibrium positions coming from main expectation values of quantized phase space position, thus subject to ordinary canonical commutation relations and the uncertainty principle. Misunderstanding a discrete model for collective latticed equilibrium averages with real position.

Comment: @Kostya: If you restrict to one band in a tight binding model, the states no longer obey canonical commutation with the crystal pseudomomentum and discrete crystal translations. The canonical commutation is for the fundamental theory, for the x operator which allows infinite precision, not for the description of one band.

Comment: @JavierÁlvarez: The p operator in a crystal is the _pseudomomentum_, it is the finite displacement symmetry which remains after the crystal breaks the symmetry to a lattice. It makes p-space periodic. The x-space is the dual to this periodic space, it's a lattice. The pseudomomentum is not the real fundamental momentum. I am not misunderstanding anything--- I know that the lattice description is effective at long distances--- but it is what lattice QM looks like, canonical commutation fails, you just have a wavefunction on a lattice. That's why I dislike the two answers here.

Comment: @RonMaimon Aren't you basically saying that *"if one starts with discretized space, then one will arrive at discretized space"* ?

Comment: @Kostya: I am saying that if you start with a periodic potential, and restrict attention to one band, you have a natural realization of discrete space. You get discrete X naturally in QM from band theory, it's an important part of the theory. The position operator defined in one band is just the discrete space quantum mechanics, and it does not obey canonical commutation relations. I explained in more detail in the expanded answer. Of course, if one starts with a discrete space, one stays in a discrete space, even after defining discrete translations and imposing discrete translation symmetry.

Comment: @RonMaimon: one may dislike many things depending on one's conceptualization of scientific models and theories. But that nevertheless does not allow to mix two different concepts in order to justify one's answer. I explain my position on an addition in my answer.

Comment: @JavierÁlvarez: I dislike it not because of "conceptualization of scientific models of theories", but because the assumption of canonical commutation is exactly equivalent to the assumption of continuous space, and it is obvious that one implies the other. If someone is asking why X is discrete, one cannot use canonical commutators to argue it, because it is an equivalent assumption. You need to understand what a discrete X QM looks like, and argue that it doesn't correspond to nature, not that it is forbidden by a mathematical identity which is derived from continuity assumption.

Comment: @RonMaimon: Indeed, although I stressed that the continuity assumption only guarantees continuity for the spectrum of only one of a pair of canonically conjugated observables. That justifies part of the argument, and the other as you say must be justified by correspondence with nature. I just try to emphasize that I am allowed also to dislike things, in this case I dislike putting at the same conceptual level quantum models for localization relative to a lattice made up of atoms with quantum spacetime per se.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what one defines as "position".

In crystals, for example, there exists a [three dimensional grid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_structure) on which the atoms are allowed , stacked in unit cells, so there is quantization in space to be observed, and quantum mechanical solutions are involved . More numerous are the interference solutions of qm waves which also display a quantization of space, where some positions are more probable than othes. So it is not true that position is not quantizable.

All the solutions where the energy is quantized involve matter and potentials also. A free particle does not display a quantization of energy as it does not display quantization of position.

If the question is addressing whether intrinsically space is quantized,     as it would be also  if one asked if energy is intrinsically quantized, i.e. comes in a minimum packet,  that is another question.

Answer (score -1):

One must take into consideration the fact that the notion of 'particle position' in quantum mechanics is meaningless. One cannot talk about the position of a particle just like one cannot talk about a specific path taken by the particle. The position of a particle in quantum mechanics is not a dynamic variable like it is in Newtonian mechanics, it does not exist as such. The commutation relation [p,x]=ih(bar) used by some tells us, that it is not possible to measure both x and p with arbitrarily high accuracy, hence Heisenberg's uncertainty principle results from it. A good clue whether position is quantised or not can be found by observing the TDSE (time dependent Schrodinger equation.) The mathematical structure of the equation, being a differential equation in x,y,z and t, requires that both position and time must be continuous variables. This requirement is a necessity for the definition of the wave function, but nobody knows where the particle described by the wave function actually is, let alone whether its position is quantised or not! One should not confuse the quantisation of the electronic orbitals in atoms with position quantisation.

Comment: In non-relativistic quantum mechanics position *is* a dynamical variable, according to the usual definition: an operator that evolves according to the equation of motion $\dot{x} = i [H,x]$ in the Heisenberg picture. It is only in QFT that position is demoted to a continuous index, like time in non-relativistic QM. Also, it is not "meaningless" to talk about the position of a particle, it is simply that you cannot know the position to arbitrary precision, due to the commutation relations as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for you response. The question is both mathematical and physical. Ehrenfest's theorem can give the evolution of the mean position, <x>, of the particle accurately. If as you say "..., it is simply that you cannot know the position to arbitrary precision, ..." then, is it still meaningful asking where the particle is? The impossibility of knowing exactly where the particle is, is not subject to improvents by higher precision  measurements, but it requires a compromise in the precision of the momentum. Only the wave function can tell us where the particle can be, but probabilistically.

Comment: I would argue that position is a meaningful concept, it just has to be revised from the naive classical concept. It is surely meaningful to ask where an electron is. For example, Young's double slit experiment relies on distinguishing where electrons land on a screen (obviously with some intrinsic uncertainty); this is how one builds up the famous interference pattern. Etcetera etcetera. But anyhow, this is more a matter of terminology/philosophy than physics, I just wanted to bring to your attention the possibility that your phrasing could be a bit misleading if taken literally.

Comment: Thanks for that. Bohr and Einstein argued, about the meaning of QM and whether objective reality of things makes any sense, untill the end of their lives! The thing that is important is what is demonstrated by the experiment.  To say that the particle has gone through one slit or the other in Young's DSE is one thing. When you do the experiment to test this out, you soon find that the interference pattern is gone and for a good reason. The spot of the electron position on the screen is only a result of its interaction, w-f collapse as they call it. So far Bohr seems to have won the argument!