# Rigorous proof that energy level of helium is discretized

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics, discrete

For the hydrogen atom, a simple separation of variables give the energy eigenvalue of the Schrodinger operator for one electron in a spherical potential. It is well known that there are no such explicit solutions for the helium atom. However, is there a rigorous mathematical proof that the helium atom's Hamiltonian operator indeed has discretized eigenvalues?

Comment: This very close to, and possibly a duplicate of, [How to prove bound state's spectrum must be discrete and scattering state's spectrum must be continuous?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/282574/)

Comment: It sounds to me like OP is asking for an existence proof for bound states, which is not addressed in the post you mention. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02730332 discusses this question in a simplified setting with no spin