# Why the eigenvalues of hamiltonian are discrete in bounded systems (only discrete energy levels)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, operators, eigenvalue, discrete

In one dimensional motion the general potential is given as in the figure above 
When energy is between V min and V 1 the energy levels are discrete like in the potential barrier and well example or when the system is bounded like in the infinite square well potential.  Why is this so? Why they are not continuous. 
The solution of these problems by applying boundary conditions give discrete energy level but I can't figure out why?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65636/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39208/2451 and links therein.