# Do non-vanishing boundaries conditions necessarily force a discrete/quantized set of solutions for the Schrödinger Equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, boundary-conditions, discrete

I was reviewing past exams and I found a question where I could give no satisfactory answer. The core of the question is the following:
If there are boundary conditions, does this necessarily imply, that the solutions to the time-independent Schrödinger equation are quantized, i.e. there are only countably many solutions?
By the expression "has a boundary conditions" I want to specifically exclude the free particle i.e. $V=0$.
Is there a rigid mathematical proof for this?

Comment: Please note that you must *always* have boundary (and initial) conditions of some kind when you're solving a partial differential equation, such as Schrödinger's. Without them there's no specific solution.Which conditions do you have in mind?

Comment: What are the boundary conditions for a free particle?

Comment: They are expressed in the form of limits, for example that $\psi(x,t) \to 0$ in a specific way as $x \to \infty$. That's a boundary condition.

Comment: That actually makes my question a lot easier: Is this the only boundary condition for which there are uncountably many possible states ?

Comment: Note that "free particle" is ambiguous though: do you have a bounded or unbounded domain?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65636/2451 and links therein.