# All periodic phenomena should have quantized energy levels?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, discrete

I was watching [a Lecture](https://youtu.be/ePA1zq56J1I?t=2460) by Douglas Hofstadter on "*Albert Einstein on Light; Light on Albert Einstein*". And there was a slide which said that Einstein had idea that

> All periodic phenomena should have quantized energy levels.

Can some one explain such idea? Thanks.

Comment: You might look into the "old quantum theory" where this connection was quite explicit.  It's also known as Wilson-Sommerfeld quantization, and it explicitly applies to periodic phenomena.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_quantum_theory

Comment: The "quantum" in quantum mechanics comes from the natural action of $U(1)$ on states. This action corresponds to an observable (charge) whose eigenvalues are integers. Thus, any time the energy depends on charge, we get quantized energy levels. For more on this, Woit's Quantum Theory, Groups, and Representations is excellent. I can expand this into a more complete answer if you like, but I get the sense it's more than you're really asking for, so for now I'm just leaving it as a comment for the interested reader.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Quantisation" does not actually arise from principle of Quantum Mechanics. Nowhere in the postulates of QM you see that the energy levels are quantised. The quantisation of energy levels arise because of the boundary conditions you impose to solve the Schrodinger Equation. Furthermore, not all systems are quantised (e.g free particle has continuous energy spectra).

To see a classical "quantisation" of spectrum, consider a taut string that is fixed by both ends (say at $x = 0$ and $x = L$). We also impose that the string cannot displace in both ends. This is essentially a boundary condition that imposes $\psi(0,t) = \psi(L,t) = 0$, where $\psi(x,t)$ denotes the vertical displacement of the string. If we are to have waves that in this string, they need to obey the appropriate boundary conditions. Suppose a wave is given by

$$ \psi(x,t)\sim \sin(kx)\sin(\omega t)$$

The boundary conditions imply

$$ \sin(kL) = 0$$

which means that $k = \frac{n\pi}{L}$. Therefore the allowed solutions must have quantised wavelengths. This is true for any valid wave that travels in this rope.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "Principles" and "postulates" are not the same thing. The phrase "postulates of QM" refers to the axioms of the mathematical formulation of QM as a mathematical formalism.

Answer (score 9):

It is a general consideration, there is no specific paper. The Fourier transform of a periodic function is discrete. If the wavefunction evolves periodically in time, there must be a discrete energy spectrum.

Answer (score 6):

The paper you want to read is by Sir Nevill Mott:

> Mott, Sir Nevill. "On teaching quantum phenomena."  Contemporary Physics 5.6 (1964): 401-418

wherein Mott argues that it is an *experimental* fact that "quantization applies to any movement of particles within a confined space, or any periodic motion, but not to unconfined motion."

Confined motion implies boundary conditions.  For instance, since $\psi$ must eventually be $0$ well outside the region where the particle is confined, only *some* solutions of the Schrodinger equation (usually labelled by discrete indices) will eventually be $0$ in the correct way.

One should be careful here about the use of *periodic*.  It may be that the radial motion (motion in time of the radius) is periodic with a period $T_r$ and that the angular motion (motion in time of the angle $\theta$) is periodic with a period $T_\theta$.  This occurs generally in central force problems.  However, if the periods are not commensurate, i.e. if $T_r/T_\theta$ is not the ratio of two integers, then the motion in $(r,\theta)$ space will never exactly repeat itself, even if the motions in $r$ and $\theta$ are individually periodic.  In your case, I believe "periodic" refers to the periodic motion of the individual variables.

Answer (score 2):

A phenomenon periodic *in time* clearly has discrete frequencies/energies, cf. the theory of [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series).

However, Douglas Hofstadter/Albert Einstein are referring to phenomena periodic *in space.*  A periodic space$^1$ can be viewed as a [compact space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space). A *compact* region of phase space has a *finite* number of number of states, cf. e.g. my related Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/39214/2451).

--

$^1$ Here we assume for simplicity that the spatial boundary conditions (BCs) are periodic as well. If the BCs are different (say instead Dirichlet BCs, as one would expect of e.g. a realistic crystal of finite volume), then the above analysis is limited to bulk properties that are not affected by the BCs.