# What is the reason for discreteness in energy level when an electron (electron-hole pair) is confined?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, discrete, quantum-dots

I studied about quantum confinement for a presentation on Quantum Well, wire and dots and came across a term 'Quantum Confinement', it said quantum confinement leads to discrete in energy level. And confinement occurs when the de-Broglie wavelength matches the dimension of the confined space. The thing I don't understand is how it leads to the discreteness in the energy level which were continuous when the electron (electron-hole pair) was not confined.

Comment: How much do you know of quantum theory? It seems like you don't know enough to accept the standard argument for it.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I wouldn't say I know a lot. Please explain if you know.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39208/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks